# non linear optimization

Tags: matlab, nonlinear-optimization

How to solve this optimization problem using matlab or some other tool. I know that, *this is a convex problem with non-linear constraint* $\rho\geq \rho_{min}$ ,  so i have tried many times it in matlab under various headings but i am not getting proper results. I will be obliged if anyone could help me to solve it. Thanks a ton in advance.
\begin{equation}
\underset{p_{s},p_{r}} {\text {minimize}}
\quad C = w_1.(\frac{p_{s}+p_{r}}{p_{max}}) + w_2.{\frac{\rho_{min}}{\rho}}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
 \begin{aligned}
        \text{subject to} \quad
    & \rho\geq \rho_{min},\quad  \text{non linear constraint}\\
    &  p_{s}+p_{r}\leq p_{max},\quad \text{linear constraint}\\
    &   p_{s}\geq 0, p_{r}\geq 0.
 \end{aligned}
 \end{equation}

where , \begin{equation}
\rho = \frac{\phi_{1}\phi_{2}p_{s}p_{r}}{\phi_{1}p_{s} + \phi_{2}p_{r} + 1},\\
\& \quad  w_{1}+w_{2}=1,\& w_{1}=.5,w_{2}=.5\\ \phi_{1}=1000;
\phi_{2}=1000.\\ \rho_{min}=10;\quad  \& \quad p_{max}=100.
\end{equation}

Comment: There is *rarely* need to write ALL IN CAPS.

Comment: Whoa! I can see your title from across the room.

Comment: Yeah baby, bigger is better :)

Comment: have you tried re-writing the non-linear constraint you mentioned, so that there won't be a fraction and then solved it?. Looks like a communication theory problem :)

Comment: @dineshdileep yes it is a comm. problem. i need to solve it for 10000 different values of $\phi_1 and \phi_2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Maple:

```
> C:= w1*(ps + pr)/pmax + w2*rhomin/rho;
> cons:= [rho >= rhomin, ps + pr <= pmax];
> rho:= phi1*phi2*ps*pr/(phi1*ps+phi2*pr+1);
> w1:= 1/2; w2:= 1/2; phi1:= 1000; phi2:= 1000;
> rhomin:= 10; pmax:= 100;
> Optimization:-Minimize(C,cons,assume=nonnegative);
```

$$[.0200049975024967248, [pr = 1.00049962527872, ps = 1.00049962527872]]$$

Comment: sir please tell me how to do it in matlab. actually i have to repeat the optimization for 10000 random values of $\phi_1 and \phi_2$. I have been trying it, from the last two days under the heading interior point by supplying gradient and hessian.
 but it is not working