# maple : how to extract the data.

Tags: maple

while doing optimization in MAPLE, i am getting the output in the form of a list, which is as follows.
\begin{equation}
t=[.366595121038205462, [pr = 14.2982930082790, ps = 22.5165237470778]]
\end{equation}
I just want to extract the value $pr \quad\&\quad ps $ from $t$, and store it in x and y respectively. Please help me.

till now i have used **whattype()** in order to check the type of **t**. And it comes out to be a **list**. Now i have to extract the floating values of **ps** and **pr** and put them in **x** and **y** respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is sometimes referred to as 2-argument eval. It's nicer than assigning those values to `pr` and `ps` because it allows those names to continue to be used directly (as names) in forming new expressions.

```
t:=[.366595121038205462,[pr=14.2982930082790,ps=22.5165237470778]]:

eval(pr,t[2]);

                   14.2982930082790

eval(ps,t[2]);

                   22.5165237470778
```

And you can use it in compound formula too, all together.

```
eval(  ps^2 - sin(pr), t[2] );

                     506.0067945
```

Comment: i salute u sir....thank u very much. actually i have to take this data to matlab and then repeat this for 10000 random values of $\phi1 and \phi2$. see this question if u want http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301952/non-linear-optimization .  THANKS A TON ACER........